# Use admin-ajax.php outside of wordpress theme

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress

I am developing custom backend area which is outside of wordpress theme.

I've enabled wordpress functions via calling `wp-load.php`.

What is best solution to continue using wordpress ajax actions as they are? Add admin-ajax.php to my folder or is there a better way?

Comment: I believe as long as you have called `wp-load.php` you should be able to call all WP Functions, including the admin-ajax, you just need to localize the script.

Comment: @GavinThomas I created custom actions.php file and added my action there, but it is showing me 500 Bad request, but when I add same function with actions inside theme functions.php it works

Comment: I don't quite understand this - if you use the entry point wp-admin/admin-ajax WordPress loads itself (i.e., it calls wp-load.php). It seems to me there is nothing that you have to do. The WordPress installation can stay as it is. Of course some of it won't be used and some storage will be wasted but storage is very cheap now days.

Comment: even simple `add_action("wp_enqueue_scripts", "lf_scripts");` is not being recognized in my index.php file @magenta

Comment: action 'wp_enqueue_scripts' is only done if you are using a WordPress theme to generate the front-end page. If you are directly generating the front-end page i.e., you are not using a WordPress theme to generate the front-end page then the actions that the theme calls such as 'wp_enqueue_scripts' will of course not be called. If you do not use the theme framework then it becomes your responsibility to provide the theme's functionality.

Comment: A suggestion - it occurs to me that you really need to better understand how WordPress works. In my opinion the easiest way to learn this is to write your own theme. If you do this you will really understand how WordPress is generating the front-end page. You will then know what the theme framework is providing and thus what you need to do yourself if you don't use the theme framework.

Comment: I know how all that works. Just wanted to be sure there is no other workaround here.

Comment: Then you must understand add_action( "wp_enqueue_scripts", ... ) cannot be used outside of the theme framework unless you implement its functionality in your own code.

Comment: yes I know, thanks @magenta

Answer (score 1):

You could just use a RewriteRule to your `.htaccess` above the regular permalink rewrite rules:

```
RewriteRule ^ajax$ /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php [L]
```

Now send your AJAX requests to `example.com/ajax`, and never miss core changes to that file after upgrades.

More information [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/83650/adding-admin-ajax-php-to-the-frontend-good-or-bad-idea).

Comment: What exactly is in your action file?

Comment: I have the function action where I do some actions inside that function @ProEvilz